# how to retrieve the most recent file from a folder in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent file added or modified in a directory. The code i got on one of the forums use the method below:

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir('MYDIRECTORY')
filelist = filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), filelist)
newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
```

i put my directory there and it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
  File "test.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NAME OF FILE'
```

with the name of the newest file shown above. So it is finding the file, but what could be the problem. Please help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the **full text** of the code you are actually running. The code you give works fine for me when using `"."` as `MYDIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of `not os.path.isdir(x)` you should use `os.path.isfile(x)`.
2. `filter` is deprecated; list comprehensions are preferred:

   ```
   filelist = [f for f in filelist if os.path.isfile(f)]
   ```
3. `os.listdir` just gives you the names of the items in the directory, not full paths. To get full paths, you need to do something like `os.path.join('MYDIRECTORY', f)`.

So all fixed up it should look like:

```
import os

rootpath = 'MYDIRECTORY'
filelist = [os.path.join(rootpath, f) for f in os.listdir(rootpath)]
filelist = [f for f in filelist if os.path.isfile(f)]
newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` does not include the directory you are listing in the paths that are returned. So you either have to `os.chdir("MYDIRECTORY")` into it before you call `os.stat(x)`, or prepend the name of the directory like `os.stat("MYDIRECTORY/" + x)`.

Or `chdir` into it beforehand and use `listdir` on the current directory like `os.listdir(".")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`os.listdir` returns file *names*, not *paths*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). While it may seem that the next command (filtering on [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)) works given just the name, you should note that `isdir` returns `False` when no object exists with that name.

What you need to do is combine the path with the file names:

```
import os

dirname = 'MYDIRECTORY'
filenames = os.listdir(dirname)
filepaths = [os.path.join(dirname, filename) for filename in filenames]
files = [f for f in filepaths if not os.path.isdir(f)]
newest = max(files, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
```

Note that I replaced the filter call with a list comprehension. This is considered more 'Pythonic' (eww), but I did it because list comprehensions are typically faster than filter/map in Python.