# How to SEARCH among the RECENT FILES USED IN PC using PYTHON 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Searching would be like:

1. first searched at the recent files
2. from recent files to their drives and dir's
3. avoiding other dir's and also you can add any other intelligent ideas.

Best regards!
Im stuck with so many files...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to retrieve the most recent file from a folder in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425685/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-file-from-a-folder-in-python)

Comment: Hi, Is it about the recent files for the whole PC (or) just a folder that you will pass as input. Are you looking for a specific operating system ?

Comment: @Soundararajan that's about the recent files in whole pc. As like 'quick access' finds so many files Im trying computer to search at there first. And

Comment: @Roshan I Don't understand what's said there.So forth I Don't think that fullfiills my answer. But at first I have to find the recent files in allwhere. Then the search.

Comment: See if you guys can answer that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673335/show-a-file-as-suggestion-if-the-filename-contains-at-least-words-from-user-inpu