# Show a file as suggestion if the filename contains at least words from user_input

Tags: python

Q/A: 
 I need to find like I'm searching for "My story part 1.pdf". I should get that on a suggestion by searching " Story 1". I have split to 'Story'  & '1'. That's fine. but  HOW DO I SAY - SEARCH THESE TWO WORDS IN MY DIRECTORY AND SHOW ME AS SUGGESTION IF YOU GET ANY FILES HAVING AT LEAST THESE NAME. THERE can be more or fewer words but at least these
What I have to add/remove to the code?  ‌

```
Import os

word =input("Enter file name ") 
words= word.split()
path =os.listdir('.')

for files in path :
    for file in files :
```

if the list word is in the file_name then print the file

```
        if words **is in** file :
```

dont know about  **is in** part.
print 3 files that're similar.
Show the file if it contains at least the user_input.

```
           print(file[-3:])
```

If exactly found then open the file.add the opening process.

```
        elif word == file :
           print("heres the file: ")
        else :
           print("no result")
```

Its not working as i thought.here file means the titles of files in path.And if user_input contains at least of their title_name then show it as suggestion. Sep= ' '.

Comment: What exactly your question?

Comment: @Gabip My question is how i set this code to my title that is show  file in suggestion if the user_input contains at least any words or ints of file_names in paths

Answer (score 0):

- read the input and split at  sapce

  `word= input("Enter file name ")`
- if you decide to os.listdir() :

  - `matches_found=False
     similars=[]
     for i in os.listdir('.'):
            if i==word:
               matches_found=True
               print("found file - {}".format(i))
               break
            [similars.append(i) for  x in word.split(" ") if x in i]
     if similars!=[]:
         print("Similar files -\n{}".format("\n".join(similars)))
         exit(0)
     if not matches_found: 
            print("No Such Files in this dir")`
- instead of os.listdir , if you are on linux, please refer to shell_output function here [here](https://github.com/vaddisrinivas/small_script/blob/master/op.py)

  - if you decide to use this function there are a lot of benefits, your code can be

    - `matches_found=False
      similars=[]
      for i in shell_output("ls").splitlines():
          if i==word:
             matches_found=True
             print("found file - {}".format(i))
             break
          [similars.append(i) for  x in word.split(" ") if x in i]
      if similars!=[]:
       print("Similar files -\n{}".format("\n".join(similars)))
       exit(0)
      if not matches_found: 
          print("No Such Files in this dir")`

Please let me know if this helps :)

Comment: I'm on windows.  So no shell_output.  i need to find like im searching for "My story part 1.pdf". I should get that on suggestion by searching " Story 1". I have splitted  to 'Story'  & '1'. That's fine.but  HOW DO I SAY - SEARCH THESE TWO WORDS IN MY DIRECTORY AND SHOW ME AS SUGGESTION IF YOU GET ANY FILES HAVING AT LEAST THESE NAME. THERE can be more or less words but at least these